# Call Play 2 REST API with AngularJS (CORS Problems)

Tags: ajax, angularjs, rest, playframework-2.0

I am developing an AngularJS application calling a REST API developed with Play Framework 2.2.0.

I have a problem related to Cross-domain ajax calls as the Angular application and the Play one will not be hosted on the same domain.

Here is the JS call in my Angular service :

```
    $http
        .post("http://localhost:9001/category/list", { langCode: 'fr-FR' })
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            callback(data.items);
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("Error Data : " + data);
            console.log("Error Status : " + status);
        });
```

Here is the route in my Play app :

`POST  /category/list  controllers.catalog.ProductCategoryController.list()`

- If I don't send any data in the request, everything works fine
- If I send data, I have Ajax errors concerning ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS

The only workaround I have is the following :

- Intercept all requests in Global class and add the headers

  `@Override
  public Action onRequest(Request request, Method method) {
      return new Action.Simple() {
          @Override
          public Promise<SimpleResult> call(Context ctx) throws Throwable {
              Logger.debug("Intercepting request and applying CORS headers...");
              ctx.response().setHeader(Controller.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, "*");
              ctx.response().setHeader(Controller.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS, "Content-Type");
              return delegate.call(ctx);
          }
      };
  }`
- Add another route with OPTIONS in routes

`OPTIONS  /category/list  controllers.catalog.ProductCategoryController.list()`

**Is there a way of making the integration simpler than that ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no CORS support out of the box in play; that's a situation I'd like to see changed, but for now you've identified a wart.

The good news is that you can manage a global workaround **if** you are OK having one CORS setting for all of your resources. It can be done in a couple of ways, one of which you identified. My inclination would be to go with a low level OPTIONS route.

Something like:

```
OPTIONS        /*path                         controllers.Application.options()
```

From there, your handler definition can be something like:

```
Ok("").withHeaders(
      "ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS" -> "GET, POST, PUT, PATCH",
      "ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS"->"Content-Type", 
      "ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN" -> "*"
)
```

It's not super clean, but until Play adds something a bit more workable, I think it's your best option over making tons of OPTIONS routes (again, assuming you're comfortable with a global CORS setting)

Comment: This solution is more maintainable than mine thanks ! I accept it for now, we'll see how the framework will handle this in the future.

Comment: hey @Damiya, i also faced the same problem when uploading videos to `brightcove` using angular and play-framework but above solution is not worked for me. My angular code as like : `url: 'http://api.brightcove.com/services/post',
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': file.type
              },
              method: 'POST',`

Answer (score -1):

You have to enable CORS support to your Play web server.  The following url do have plenty of how-to for configurating server enabling the cross origin support:

http://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: As I said to Ramesh, the server accepts my requests, the main problem is that I have to specify a route twice (OPTIONS and POST)