# Brightcove: CORS error using Play-Framework 2.3.x and Angular-JS

Tags: angularjs, scala, playframework-2.3, brightcove

I am using `brightcove` for managing videos in my sample application. My sample application based on `Play-Framework 2.3.x`, `Scala`, `Angular-JS`. The problem is that, i am using `Angular-JS` for uploading videos to `brightcove` server using `Brightcove apis`. My Angular code as below:

```
 $scope.uploadProcess=   $upload.upload({
          url: 'http://api.brightcove.com/services/post',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': file.type
          },
          method: 'POST',
          fields: {
        "method": "create_video", 
      "params": {
       "video": {
           "name": filename,
           "tags": [],
           "shortDescription": filename,
           "itemState": "ACTIVE"
          },
  -------------------------------------------
```

When i send the request, browser return following error on response.

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://api.brightcove.com/services/post. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

From searching on Google i found some solutions like [Call Play 2 REST API with AngularJS (CORS Problems)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21948495/call-play-2-rest-api-with-angularjs-cors-problems). But nothing is worked. i am really stuck at that scenario, please provide the solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do these kind of requests from the browser, you need to make sure that CORS is enabled on the server.

Brightcove does not seem to have that enabled, at least that whats the error message states.

The easiest solution would probably be, that you post the file through your backend.